# Efficient way to look in list of lists?

Tags: python, numpy

I am continuously creating a randomly generated list, `New_X` of size 10, based on 500 columns.

Each time I create a new list, it must be unique, and my function `NewList` only returns `New_X` once it hasn't already been created and appended to a `List_Of_Xs`

```
def NewList(Old_List):

end = True
while end == True:

    """ Here is code that generates my new sorted list, it is a combination of elements 
        from Old_List and the other remaining columns,
        but the details aren't necessary for this question. """ 

    end = (List_Of_Xs == np.array([New_X])).all(axis=1).any()

List_Of_Xs.append(New_X)
return New_X
```

My question is, is the line `end = (List_Of_Xs == np.array([New_X])).all(axis=1).any()` an efficient way of looking in `List_Of_Xs`?

My `List_Of_Xs` can grow to a size of over 100,000 lists long, so I am unsure if this is inefficient or not.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So, is that `List_Of_Xs` a list of lists with 10 elements per list? Are those elements integers? Is there an upper and lower bound to those ints?

Comment: I'd make `New_X` a tuple, and check if it is in a set `Set_of_Xs`.   Especially with small list of 10 elements that should be faster than doing this array comparison.

Comment: `List_of_Xs==np.array([New_X])` not only makes `New_X` into an array, but it does so for `List_of_Xs` each time.  Creating an array from a list of lists is not a time-trivial task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I observed in a comment, the array comparison is potentially quite slow, especially as the list gets large.  It has to create arrays each time, which consumes time.

Here's a set implementation

Function to create a 10 element list:

```
def foo(N=10):
    return np.random.randint(0,10,N).tolist()
```

Function to generate lists, and print the unique ones

```
def foo1(m=10):
    Set_of_Xs = set()
    while len(Set_of_Xs)<m:
        NewX = foo(10)
        tx = tuple(NewX)
        if not tx in Set_of_Xs:
            print(NewX)
            Set_of_Xs.add(tx)
    return Set_of_Xs
```

Sample run.  As written it doesn't show if there are duplicates.

```
In [214]: foo1(5)
[9, 4, 3, 0, 9, 4, 9, 5, 6, 3]
[1, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5]
[6, 7, 2, 0, 6, 9, 0, 7, 0, 8]
[9, 5, 6, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 6, 9]
[9, 2, 6, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0, 0, 4]
Out[214]: 
{(1, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5),
 (6, 7, 2, 0, 6, 9, 0, 7, 0, 8),
 (9, 2, 6, 0, 2, 7, 2, 0, 0, 4),
 (9, 4, 3, 0, 9, 4, 9, 5, 6, 3),
 (9, 5, 6, 3, 3, 5, 6, 9, 6, 9)}
```

Comment: thank you, this ended up being faster as my `Set_of_Xs` gets fairly large. Do you think that it would be easier if my function `NewX` created them in tuple form?

Comment: Converting list to tuple (or back) isn't a big deal.  It's just that `set` requires a `tuple` (since it is immutable).

Answer (score 1):

So let me get this straight since the code doesn't appear complete:
1. You have an old list that is constantly growing with each iteration
2. You calculate a list 
3. You compare it against each of the lists in the old list to see if you should break the loop?

One option is to store the lists in a set instead of a List of List.
Comparing an element against all the elements of a list would be an O(n) operation each iteration. Using a set it should be O(1) avg... Although you may be getting O(n) every iteration until the last.

Other thoughts would be to calculate the md5 of each element and compare those so you're not comparing the full lists.

Comment: The old list is not constantly growing in each iteration. Each old list is stored in a List_Of_Xs and each new list is compared against the List_Of_Xs, if the new list isn't already in the List_Of_Xs, the loop is broken.